# Understanding the time complexities of the R-Tree?

Tags: database, indexing, r-tree

A quick search on Wikipedia reveals that the R-Tree's worst case performance for a search is undefined and the average case is O(logMn).

I suppose the worst case is this way because we can't know how many times a search has to be performed in this structure until we find the item, indeed, Guttman does say that "more than one subtree under a node visited may need to be searched, hence it is not possible to guarantee good worst-case performance." Can we express the worst case in terms of the number of searches that have to be performed?

Regarding the average case, I do not understand how this is calculated. And what about the best case?

Answer (score 3):

I'd say worst case is O(n + logM n): Imagine you store lots of overlapping rectangles in the R-Tree. Now store a single small rectangle that is located in the area where all other rectangles overlap. A query for that rectangle will have to traverse all subtrees: nodes -> O(logM n) and entries -> O(n).

Best case is O(log n). An R-Tree has the same depth in every branch, and data is only stored in leaf-nodes, so you will always have to traverse O(logM n) nodes and all entries in that node, so it should be O(M * logM n).

I'm not sure you can really calculate average O(logM n). But if you have some average normally distributed data (whatever that means) with few overlaps (whatever few means) than your average query (whatever average is) should not have to traverse more than a few (1 or 2?) subtrees. I'd actually say the average is O(M * logM n), because of the traversal of M entries in a node.

Comment: Thanks but for clarification ,  isn't the worst case O (nlogMn) ? for each entry O(n), a subtree has to be trasversed O(logMn)? In your example, due to overlaps, n will be bigger.

Comment: I used 'n' as the number of data-entries (which are only contained in the leaf nodes). For a query in a badly formed tree, you would traverse all nodes once (but not more than once), which is O(logM(n)). Whenever you encounter a leaf node, you would traverse all entries, which totals to O(n). In total you traverse all nodes + all entries, hence O(n + logM(n) ).

Comment: I'm having trouble with understanding the n+logM(n) because while searching every node, many branches are being searched. So it seems to me that there should be multiple logM(n) -some constant attached to logM(n). Are you dismissing this constant ?

Comment: When you traverse a node in the tree, all you can traverse are either sub-nodes (they are included in O(logM(n)) or data entries (they are included in O(n)). Putting it another way, the tree contains in total  (logM(n) + n) traversable entries (nodes + data entries). Traversing a single element takes O(1). I'm not quite sure what else you want traverse?
logM(n) is already the estimated number of nodes in the R-Tree.

Comment: The problem with "average" is clearly: average about what data distributions, and what queries. But if you have e.g. user locations on earth, and want to find the 1 nearest neighbor, O(logM n) - the height of the tree - is a good estimated search time. You may need to visit a few leaf nodes, but not many. But try to formalize that in a theoretical way for an "average complexity"...